# Function composition with splitOn does not work

Tags: haskell, dictionary, split

My code:

```
map head $ map (splitOn ":") inputlines
```

works just fine, inputlines is a list; However, this code does not work:

```
map head . (splitOn ":") inputlines
```

Nor

```
map head . (splitOn ":") $ inputlines
```

My thinking is that `head . (splitOn ":")` makes it equivalent to a single function. Then use map to apply the single function on list `inputlines`. But it does not work, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
map (head . splitOn ":") inputlines
```

it will work.

In case of `map head . (splitOn ":") inputlines`, Haskell considers `inputlines` as argument of partially applied `splitOn`. The same holds for `map head . (splitOn ":") $ inputlines`, this first evaluates `inputlines`, then applies it to `splitOn` again.

Answer (score 0):

its

```
map (head . splitOn ":") inputlines
```